# How to add HTTP endpoint to ASP.NET Core 6 app?

Tags: asp.net-core, http, https, .net-6.0

I created an ASP.NET Core 6 app with "Configure for HTTPS" checked during project creation. For testing purposes I now need a plain HTTP endpoint. How can I add such an endpoint?

My code currently looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World! - use /graphql");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Could you share your `launchSettings.json`?

Comment: @Serhii See my answer below :-) And your question already solved my issue somehow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Serhii and Serge pointed me to the `launchSettings.json` (note that it's inside the `Properties` folder!). That's how it looks like:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:20380",
      "sslPort": 44329
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "TestProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7090;http://localhost:5090",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the line

```
 "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7090;http://localhost:5090",
```

and note that the second URL is plain HTTP. I could call this URL without any issues (started project normally using F5, HTTPS link is called automatically, but one can just switch manually to the HTTP link in the browser).

So, nothing to do for me, no configuration change was needed etc :-)